# What is the use of function without suite(body)?

Tags: python, function

We can define a function without a body using `pass`. For example:

```
def testfunc():
      pass
```

Can anyone help me in understanding the use of this function without body?

Comment: It's very useful for lecturers who want you to implement functions :)

Comment: Could you provide some context for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one reason is to use it as a stub function while you are creating tests before you really implement the function. This is usual when you are using a [test-driven development methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).